# Getting InvalidCastException on GetCallbackChannel

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using WCF to do duplex communication.  Intent is to be able to send messages back and forth between a client app and a windows service.  Communication from the client app works fine, but attempting to use the callback channel for communication from the service back to the client fails with an InvalidCastException whenever I try to get the callback service.

Service Contracts:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IPipeListenerCallbackService), SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IPipeListenerService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void SendMessage(string message);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IPipeListenerCallbackService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void SendMessage(string message);
}
```

Implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class PipeListenerService : IPipeListenerService
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        //do something...
    }


    public IPipeListenerCallbackService Callback
    {
        get
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPipeListenerCallbackService>();
        }
    }

}
```

Service code to host / open the WCF ServiceHost:

```
try
{
    PipeListenerService service = new PipeListenerService();
    Uri pipeLocation = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/" + this.PipeName);

    this.pipeServiceHost = new ServiceHost(service, pipeLocation);
    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    this.pipeServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPipeListenerService), binding, "MessagePipe");

    this.pipeServiceHost.Open();                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do proper error handling here                
}
```

Elsewhere in the service code, I am getting to the point where I want to actually call the SendMessage on the Callback, so I am doing the following:

```
PipeListenerService theService = this.pipeServiceHost.SingletonInstance as PipeListenerService;
if (theService != null)
{
   theService.Callback.SendMessage(message);
}
```

The exception is being thrown at the point where it is getting the Callback property.

Exception is:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' to type 'CommUtil.IPipeListenerCallbackService'.
>      at System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.GetCallbackChannelT
>      at .PipeListenerService.get_Callback()

For reference, I created this after digesting the MSDN articles on Duplex Services for WCF [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services).  My google-fu only turned up links that were saying thinks like "Include 2nd contract as CallbackContract", which I think I am already doing.

Any suggestions are welcome, including possible alternative approaches.  One restriction is that, because the client app must run as a normal user (not admin/elevated), I cannot simply do 2 separate pipes, one hosted by the service and the other by the client, as WCF security restrictions will make the client's pipe not visible to other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question.

Essentially, my problem was that I was not saving the callback object at the correct point in its lifetime.

Looking at the samples provided, all of the callbacks were utilized as a response/reply to an inbound service call.  In my case, that would be if I were to grab it in SendMessage().

Looking at a few more samples, I found one for the Publisher / Subscriber design pattern [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/design-patterns-list-based-publish-subscribe).  The key difference is that it would save the callback object during a call to one method (Subscribe, in this case), and use it elsewhere.

Relevant code samples below:

```
public void Subscribe()  
    {  
        callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISampleClientContract>();  
        priceChangeHandler = new PriceChangeEventHandler(PriceChangeHandler);  
        PriceChangeEvent += priceChangeHandler;  
    }  

public void PriceChangeHandler(object sender, PriceChangeEventArgs e)  
    {  
        callback.PriceChange(e.Item, e.Price, e.Change);  
    }
```

So, in my specific case, my desired behavior / solution is closer to a pub/sub pattern than a call & response pattern.  So, I simply had to add an additional service method, Register(), that would save the callback object, and have the client call that service method after establishing the connection channel.